# Will my rims fit 25mm or 28mm tires?

Tags: tire, wheels

I have a hybrid Dawes, about 25 years old. I think it's currently got 700x35mm. I would like to fit thinner tires but how do I know if the rims will accept them. Is there a way to know?

Comment: How wide are the rims?  If, measured inside between the flanges, the rims are no wider than about 20mm then they should handle 25mm tires.

Comment: @DanielRHicks some of the modern rims are 21mm or even 23mm ID and work with 25mm (claimed) tires just fine. The tire will grow wider, exactly how much depends on manufacturer, but it might become as wide as 30mm. I see no reason why older rims would change anything, so I'd say your estimate is on a safe side.

Comment: (I believe there is a discussion of this on Sheldon's site or one of the tire sites, but I'm feeling too lazy to look it up.)

Comment: Looking at 25mm.

Comment: Why do you want thinner tyres?  What advantage to you expect ?  Or is it a matter of availability ?

Comment: Is is not obvious. Does it not allow to go faster on road?

Comment: There is some discussion about up to which point narrow tires are actually faster. Recently the trend is towards wider rims and tires. 25mm tires on rims with ~18mm inner width seems to be the new norm on road bikes. 28mm is now also often used on training road bikes. The tire model itself will have much more impact than the width.

Comment: I currently have 35mm. So that assume 25 or 28 with slicker treads will be faster even if 1 to 2 mph.